# How to custom cursor , include shape weight color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am implementing an input field through BasicTextField, but the width and shape of the cursor cannot be customized because it is in CoreTextfield, which is very basic.It is internal function.

Most of the parts related to the cursor in Jetpack Compose are internal methods.I cant use.

Answer (score 0):

Currently width is not configurable, You can check this issue here:

[Link](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/1669)